# factory method D.P

Tags: design-patterns, methods, factory

"it's about creating objects (products) without specifying the exact class of object that will be created". how can it be?
and if there is an abstract class that evryone inherits from it- sounds like "Polymorphism". what's the  difference anyway?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider, that we have an interface:

```
public interface IClass {}
```

Also we have two classes wich inherit that interface (or abstract class, or just any other base class):

```
public class First : IClass {}

public class Second: IClass {}
```

The first one is used to to the staff in pruduction code, and the second one you use for tests.

And you have a factory method:

```
public IClass GetClass () 
{
    if(InTest) return new Second();
    else 
    return new First();
}
```

So, code wich calls this method does not specify the  exact class that will be created. It just knows how to use it.